# How to move with icon from fontawesome in bootstrap card

Tags: html, css

I am learning web development and i need advice.
I have bootstrap card and i want to align the minus-square icon from font awesome to right but nothing work.
Do you have some ideas?
Thanks for everything! I am also sending picture to good imagine.
[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: you should send here css and html, try to set display: flex; justify-content: space-between to the header of the card

Comment: try `pull-right`?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using bs4, you could use the `float-right` class.

**Demo working snippet:**

```html
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        Basic card
        <i class="some-fa-icon float-right">&#9824;</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note that instead of the icon I have used a html unicode character and mentioned `some-fa-icon` class which would be replaced by your actual font awesome classes.